# RTMP Nginx exec_push with alaw and h264

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtmp

I have 2 RTMP servers, one NGINX with the RTMP module, and a second one that can only consume RTMP with H264 and ALAW, which will receive video from the NGINX one.

I successfully pushed my camera image to the second server using Gstreamer:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/video0" ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency key-int-max=20 ! flvmux name=flvmux ! rtmpsink location=rtmp://<second_server_ip>:1935/publish/foobar audiotestsrc ! alawenc ! flvmux.
```

Now, I need to send a video from the NGINX server to the second server, but it needs to have H264 video encoding and ALAW audio encoding.

I tried one more intermediate step, where I streamed to the NGINX server and ran

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtmpsrc location=rtmp://<nginx_ip>:1935/live/100 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency key-int-max=20 ! flvmux name=flvmux ! rtmpsink location=rtmp://<second_server_ip>:1935/publish/foobar audiotestsrc ! alawenc | flvmux.
```

but I got

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTMPSrc:rtmpsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTMPSrc:rtmpsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

What am I missing in the GStreamer command? And how can I add it to the NGINX application to automatically push the streams received? I'm ok with doing it with FFmpeg if I need to.

Thank you

EDIT:

My first server will be fed with a stream from a mobile app. This server (NGINX) is configured like this:

```
application live {
   live on;
   interleave on; 
}
```

This server should push to a second server (written in Go), which is going to convert RTMP to WebRTC so I can play the stream in a browser. As I previously stated, I have successfully streamed RTMP to the second server with GStreamer, but I want the first server to automatically push to the second, and it's that push that I been able todo yet.

EDIT 2:

I have used VLC and the encoding is H264, so no problem there. But I do need ALAW instead of MPEG AAC audio, how can I change on the NGINX server when I push it to the second server?

Comment: I dont really understand your setup. What is on first server, what is on second.. where is the pipeline for feeding the nginx? In your intermediate step - If you take stream from nginx why do you expect it to feed you raw video data? I guess (based on what/how you feed it) you will get h264 stream which you need to decode and reencode again (which is weird anyway).

Comment: @nayana I'm not sure of the encoding that NGINX gets fed, how should I find it? I have also edited the question, I hope it is clearer now!